# Known solution for sql logging for Spring jdbc template not working

Tags: sql, spring, log4j, c3p0, jdbctemplate

Below is the code in log4j.xml for enabling the sqls to be logged for jdbc template in spring.

```
<!-- SQL logging -->
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_SQL" />
    <appender-ref ref="CA" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_SQL" />
    <appender-ref ref="CA" />
</logger>
```

But it does not seem to work !!! Please help.I am using c3p0 connection pool.

Comment: And it doesn't log anything?

Comment: yes ... it does not log anything ... the sql or the bound parameters of any sort !!

Comment: Let's see your appenders

Comment: Yes, let's see or check your appenders - it's possible the appenders have a "higher" threshold, ignoring the DEBUG and TRACE statements.

[http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2012/11/jboss-spring-jdbc-sql-logging-log4j.html